# Why is my conditional formatting using a formula not working in some cells in a range?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, excel-365

I want to check whether a date in a cell at the top of 3 columns is before a set starting date in the sheet and if it is the color of the range to which this rule apply should change to grey and if the condition is not met no formatting should apply. Please see photo of what I want to achieve and the white cells which seem to be the problem.
[What needs to be achieved with conditional formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWdM9.png)

Please also see the formula in cell C4:E4 used:
=TEXT(DATE(Year;1;1) - WEEKDAY(DATE(Year;1;1);2) + (WEEKNUM(I1:K1))*7 + 1;"yyyy/mm/dd")

I tried switching between absolute values instead of relative ones but no luck. I also checked the locked status of all cells and it is set to unlocked.  I really don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: You should be using $C$4 not C4 in your formula. Also, don't use the TEXT function or your comparisons will be on an alphanumeric basis, not comparing dates - just format the cell the way you want.

Comment: @Rory - Write it up as an answer. I think you have it.